# Overriding of jsp tags and jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, jsp

Say I have a container to add widgets and a user can add two/more instances of a same widget. A widget internally loads jsp page which has html code and jQuery code and struts tags.

My JSP:

```
<div id"sample1"/>
    <-- all the html part with struts tags -->

<script>
    all the methods to perform actions
</script>
```

When the two or more widgtes are added in the same page then the selectors using jquery obviuosly wont work appropriately due to duplicate ids. So solution would be some unique id to each widget instance. But for that I have to do something like below for each element and function. How to make this process less cumbersome especially there are lot of jsps and widgtes.

```
<div id"sample1-"<s:property value="uniqueId">" />
loadSample1-"<s:property value="uniqueId">" = function () {

}
```

Comment: You mean attr selectors. like `$('elem[id^="someID"]')`.

Comment: yeah like $("#sample1").click();